# Exposed and private/local members in CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I was testing this framework and got these issues, idk why they happen and couldn't find the answer neither in Node.js docs nor in global search.

init.js

```
const { f1, v1, v2, f2 } = require('./1.js')

f2()
```

1.js

```
module.exports = {
    
    f1: function (v1) { f1(v1) },
    
    v1: 1,
    v2: this.v1 + 1,
    
    f2: function () { f1(this.v2) },
    // * error: outputs NaN .
    
    // f2: function () { this.f1(this.v2) },
    // * error: when called from importing script, crashes with `TypeError: this.f1 is not a function` .
    //  
    //  This function works if `<<name for Object>> = require('<<path>>')` syntax is used .
    
}

function f1 (v1) {
    console.log(v1)
}
```

Specific questions are:

- How to use exposed functions and variables in other exposed functions?

  Is it possible to achive with `module.exports = {` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the syntax of defining everything inside of `module.exports` object, you can refer to it in other functions' bodies either through `this` or through `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = {
  f1: function () {
    // …
  },

  f2: function () {
    this.f1()
  },

  f3: function () {
    module.exports.f1()
  },
}
```

You can't refer to the object by `module.exports` for variables (non-function properties). This is because while the property value is being calculated, `module.exports` does not exist yet.

You also can't refer to it by `this`, mainly for the same reasons: `this` refers to a different thing, not the object.

---

All of this trouble can be easily avoided (with added benefits, like making the value read-only, more fine-grained visibility control – and many more) if you define things separately from exporting them:

```
const v1 = 1

let v2 = v1 + 1

function f1(arg) {
  console.log(arg)
}

function f2() {
  f1(v2)
}

module.exports = { v1, v2, f1, f2 }
```

Comment: `<<unexpected value>> + 1 == NaN` , ty. It appears that remaining benefits worth less than scalability of ES modules. _ _ By the way,  `<<name for Object>> = require('<<path>>')` syntax is required for 1st part of your answer.

Comment: Yes, in both cases,  you access the values like `require('path/to/file').f1(arg)`